# aptana studio 3 quit unexpectedly for mac

Tags: python, aptana, macos-sierra, aptana3

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq2Hn.png) I'm trying to install Aptana Studio 3 for my Mac to begin programming in Python but after I download it from Aptana Studio and try to open it, it gives me the error message, "AptanaStudio3 quit unexpectedly." (attached is a screenshot of it)

I have enabled downloading apps from "anywhere" on the Security & Privacy settings on my mac and tried the other troubleshooting apatanastudio questions on Stack Overflow but it doesn't work. I am using macOS Sierra version 10.12.4

I'd love some guidance as to how I can open Aptana Studio 3 to start developing with Python! Thanks!